# Application skipping 600 frames

Tags: android, multithreading, performance, optimization, service

so im building this service for a application locker. it runs fine for the most part.but when i try to run the service to lock my own application(ie the app locker itself) there's a lag for like 4-5 seconds and then the lock activity launches. The logcat displays that it has skipped 600 frames and is doing too much work on the main thread. can anyone tell him how do i fix this or optimize this code

the `AppActivities` contains the name of activities that are to be ignored from launching the locker again when they are on top of the stack.eg the lockscreen activity to be shown to the user. The `allowedapp` is the last app verified by the user

```
public class LockerService extends Service {
String LockedApps[];
String allowedapp = null;
DataBaseHandler handler;
Intent pwdIntent = null;
ActivityManager am;
String[] AppActivities = { "com.packagename.Locker",
        "com.packagename.Compare_Pattern",
        "com.packagename.Captcha_Verfication",
        "com.haibison.android.lockpattern.LockPatternActivity" };
private final static Handler servicehandler = new Handler() {
    @Override
    public void handleMessage(Message msg) {

    }
};

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate();
    handler = new DataBaseHandler(this);
    am = (ActivityManager) getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
    pwdIntent = new Intent(LockerService.this, Locker.class);
    pwdIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);

}

@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return null;
}

private Runnable checkforeground = new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        handler.open();
        LockedApps = handler.getPackages();
        handler.close();
        String packname = am.getRunningTasks(1).get(0).topActivity
                .getPackageName();
        String activityname = am.getRunningTasks(1).get(0).topActivity
                .getClassName();
        SharedPreferences sp = PreferenceManager
                .getDefaultSharedPreferences(LockerService.this);
        allowedapp = sp.getString("allowedapp", "anon");
        // check if top application is mylocker application 
        if ((packname.equals("com.packagename"))
                && (allowedapp.equals("com.packagename"))) {
            // do nothing
        } 
          // check if top application is mylocker application and prevent relaunching the lockeractivity every 1.5 seconds
          else if ((packname.equals("com.packagename"))
                && !(Arrays.asList(AppActivities).contains(activityname))) {

            try {
                Editor edit = sp.edit();
                edit.putString("current_app", packname);
                edit.commit();
                startActivity(pwdIntent);
                Thread.sleep(10000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        } else if ((Arrays.asList(LockedApps).contains(packname))
                && (allowedapp.equals(packname))) {
            // do nothing
        } else if ((Arrays.asList(LockedApps).contains(packname))) {
            Editor edit = sp.edit();
            edit.putString("current_app", packname);
            edit.commit();
            startActivity(pwdIntent);
        }
        servicehandler.postDelayed(this, 1500); // 1.5 seconds
    }
};

@Override
public void onStart(Intent intent, int startId) {

    servicehandler.removeCallbacks(checkforeground);
    servicehandler.postDelayed(checkforeground, 1500);// 1.5 second
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onDestroy();
    servicehandler.removeCallbacks(checkforeground);
    stopSelf();
}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

first of all as Gabe mentioned, a runnable runs on the main Thread.To solve the frames issue You'll need to create another new thread to run your code in the background.

Try this initialize `executorService` and `LcThread` and a boolean `running_status`in your service.
The running_status variable is used to break the while loop of your thread so that stops looping in the back

```
@Override
public void onStart(Intent intent, int startId) {
    running_status = true;
    executorService = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();
    servicehandler.removeCallbacks(LcThread);
    LcThread = new LockerThread();
    executorService.submit(LcThread);

}
```

create the following class

```
class LockerThread implements Runnable {

    @Override
    public void run() {
 while(running_status){

     //copy code from your old Runnable run method here
    }   
  }
}
```

next modify the `onDestroy` method

```
@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onDestroy();
    if (executorService != null) {
        executorService.shutdown();
    }
    running_status = false;
    servicehandler.removeCallbacks(LcThread);
    stopSelf();
}
```

hope this solves your problem

Comment: thank you..there seems to be a little lag..but its significantly less then it was before

Answer (score 0):

A runnable still happens on the main thread.  Services do not have their own thread by default, they run on the UI thread.  If you want to do heavy processing in a service, you need to use a Thread or AsyncTask, so the processing does not occur on the UI thread.